# Can a regular class contain only method signatures (like an interface)?

Tags: c#

I'm looking at some code right now, and I am a little confused. This class is not an interface, but why those methods are not defined? Also, bedsides method signatures, there is a regular property. Very confusing!

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string Foo(string str1);
   public string Bar(string str, int i);

   public string myProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Maybe they are abstract? In which case the programmer expects you to create your own subclass.

Comment: What happened when you tried to compile it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is not valid as shown, and you could prove as much by trying to compile it.  For a class to contain unimplemented methods it must be declared as `abstract`, and the same applies to each unimplemented method.

`abstract` classes are conceptually similar to an interface, but they may contain implementation as well.  This makes them useful for scenarios in which some methods may share a common implementation all the way down the inheritance hierarchy, but others only have meaning when implemented by a descendant type.

Methods marked as `extern` or `partial` can also lack a body, but `extern` methods are typically interop (so it is implemented in native code), and `partial` methods will be implemented in another `.cs` file (and can be declared only in a class marked as `partial`).

As an aside, the property is fine because it is automatic (syntactical sugar which means that the backing field will be created for you and the get/set methods simply return/set that field, nothing more).

Comment: If I'd marked the class ABSTRACT, I'd never bother asking. Since, he didn't, I thought I was missing something. So, Are you reassuring me that there is a mistake there?

Comment: @Richard77: Yes, that code doesn't compile (try it yourself, should only take a few seconds).  I didn't assume anything about your knowledge of abstract/partial classes based on the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the methods as `abstract` and then you will have an `abstract` class

but why would you want to do that? if you don't have any code in a base class just use an interface

Comment: @Servy Thats right, but it still doesn't change the reason to use an interface in that case

Comment: It's certainly possible for an interface to be a good fit, but there just isn't enough information to assert that for sure.  It's possible implemented methods were omitted by the OP, or that the actual class logically represents an abstract "parent" type rather than a contract.